# CakePHP page restriction interface

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have multiple user access groups and I am currently using this code to restrict user access groups from certain pages.

```
public function add()
    {
        if($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.access_id') != '1 ')
            {
                //$this->request->session()->setFlash('You are not authorized to visit this page','flash',array('alert'=>'info'));
                $this->redirect('/dashboard');
            }
```

I want to be able to create an opencart type interface for allowing access for different pages for each user access groups.

[Opencart Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnFvM.png)

So I want to create check boxes to modify access so that admins can easily create new user access groups and modify existing ones without touching the code. The only way I can think to do this is for the check boxes to modify the code for every controller. Would someone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: You should read up on [Authorization](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#authorization). In particular, I've used [controller authorize](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize) for just this sort of thing. There are also plugins like [this one](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth) that do this sort of thing; if you can't just drop it in, it might at least give you some ideas about how some of the pieces need to come together in your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to achieve that is the ACL plugin.

https://github.com/cakephp/acl

This is how I use it (is in italian)
[image: 1]]

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer I've setup ACL and linked the tables so they all work I can view the ARO tree in the console by using "bin/cake acl view aro" but i'm unsure how to get the user interface like shown in your picture.

Comment: I've build a custom component to edit rules and a helper to check the rules on the views. Is just and intesive use of Acl\Controller\Component\AclComponent

Comment: Are there any guides to doing this I've been looking for a while but can only fine some for cake 2. I'm just not sure where to start because i'm new to cakephp.

Comment: I installed AclManager and managed to just get it working thank you for your help!